# Which one is better, Workbox or ServiceWorker?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

hi I created a project with *create-react-app* and it has a *SW* out of the box.
which is written with *Workbox* library, is Workbox better than serviceworker?
how Can i rewrite this file with just service worker without WorkBox?

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare Workbox to service workers. Workbox is a set of "JavaScript libraries for adding offline support to web apps" and it uses service workers (and other stuff) to do it's magic.

What do you want to achive?
And why do you want to rewrite the out-of-the-box file?

Answer (score 1):

Workbox is the great solution for begging and they have a lot of configuration. For example you can write you site with html and css but you like use react or angular to increase speed of development.

In the CRA you already have configurate Service Worker by Workbox to offline mode. You can read more https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/

If you need only PWA - use existing solutions

But if you need more specific solution - You can easily use workbox

And if you really want to create a custom solution you can remove all libraries and switch to js file and write custom ServiceWorker for your requirements

In general Workbox will be enough for most projects